# How come my compiler isn't able to see these functions I've created?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

So I'm currently trying to work through a book called "Crafting Interpreters" and it goes step by step through making a language. I'm writing this language in C and already running into issues. I have a couple header files with respective c files and then the main driver code. When I try to compile the code, I get this error:
[compiler error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifUKx.png)
I'm not sure what's going wrong here as I have other projects using header files and they are able to compile correctly.

```
//main
#include "common.h"
#include "chunk.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Chunk chunk;
    initChunk(&chunk);
    writeChunk(&chunk, OP_RETURN);
    freeChunk(&chunk);
    return 0;
}
```

```
//common.h
#ifndef clox_common_h
#define clox_common_h

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#endif
```

```
//chunk.h
#ifndef clox_chunk_h
#define clox_chunk_h

#include "common.h"

typedef enum {
    OP_RETURN,
} OpCode;

typedef struct {
    int count;
    int capacity;
    uint8_t* code;
} Chunk;

void initChunk(Chunk* chunk);
void freeChunk(Chunk* chunk);
void writeChunk(Chunk* chunk, uint8_t byte);

#endif
```

```
//chunk.c
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "chunk.h"
#include "memory.h"

void initChunk(Chunk* chunk) {
    chunk->count = 0;
    chunk->capacity = 0;
    chunk->code = NULL;
}

void freeChunk(Chunk* chunk) {
    FREE_ARRAY(uint8_t, chunk->code, chunk->capacity);
    initChunk(chunk);
}

void writeChunk(Chunk* chunk, uint8_t byte) {
    if (chunk->capacity < chunk->count) {
        int oldCapacity = chunk->capacity;
        chunk->capacity = GROW_CAPACITY(oldCapacity);
        chunk->code = GROW_ARRAY(uint8_t, chunk->code, 
            oldCapacity, chunk->capacity);
    }

    chunk->code[chunk->count] = byte;
    chunk->count++;
}
```

```
//memory.h
#ifndef clox_memory_h
#define clox_memory_h

#include "common.h"

#define GROW_CAPACITY(capacity) \
    ((capacity) < 8 ? 8 : (capacity) * 2)

#define GROW_ARRAY(type, pointer, oldCount, newCount) \
    (type*)reallocate(pointer, sizeof(type) * (oldCount), \
        sizeof(type) * (newCount))

#define FREE_ARRAY(type, pointer, oldCount) \
    reallocate(pointer, sizeof(type) * (oldCount), 0)

void* reallocate(void* pointer, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize);

#endif
```

```
//memory.c
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "memory.h"

void* reallocate(void* pointer, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize) {
    if (newSize == 0) {
        free(pointer);
        return NULL;
    }

    void* result = realloc(pointer, newSize);
    if (result == NULL) exit(1);
    return result;
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Can you include the exact compiler command(s) you're using to build this? It's very possible that while you're including the *header* for chunk, you're not actually linking against the chunk.c translation unit.

Comment: Compiling `main.c` is not enough, you need `gcc -Wall main.c chunk.c memory.c`

Comment: how can the compiler know that you have more C files to compile?